# Does the name of the college you attend matter to your potential employer?

Tags: career-path, reputation

Please don't close, I'm just asking for research purposes.
I don't care if your answer is biased.

Comment: But this is opinion-based and hence off topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "This is not a question at all."

Comment: *I don't care if your answer is biased.* – But we do care and don’t like questions which invite biased answers. Also: 1) Are you talking about the actual name or the institution behind it? 2) What exactly do you mean by *matter?*

Comment: Ivy League diploma may hurt you if your interviewer is a graduate of a state school and you act arrogant (or perceived as such). You have to fit into the culture of the place you are applying to.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it matters.  A degree from an elite university won't get you the job if you can't pass the interviews but it will pop your resume to somewhere near the top of the pile for a closer look.